# Why does my ceiling fan light stay on even when chain is pulled?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

Both My ceiling fan and light could be turned on/off by individual chains when the wall switch was turned on. The light chain could turn off light & leave fan on and vice versa. Now the light stays on when the chain is pulled.

Comment: The switch may have failed. If so, the fix is obvious, and the light switch (as opposed to the speed switch) is a simple on/off so hard to get wrong.

Comment: The pull chain switch is probably busted and needs replacement.  Does the chain feel/click the same now when pulled, as before?

Answer (score 1):

Those switches are fairly dainty for the load that's put on them. Like any mechanical device, they have a finite lifespan.

Fortunately they're fairly easy to replace. Look for a universal replacement switch if yours mounts to a hole about 1/2" in diameter with a nut. If not, you'll probably need a proprietary part from the manufacturer.

Then you'll disconnect power and open the light kit. That's often simply a matter of removing the nut at the center. Use wire nuts, butt splicers or whatever connectors are available in the unit to connect the new switch.

Comment: Take a picture of the wiring first!